How can I login to 4th party API using my credentials + generating a JWT?
I'm trying to log in to a 4th party website's API using a POST request and javascript. Normally this would be easy if I created the API, or worked directly with the creator, but neither is the case here. To explain why: I want to use my login to access some private endpoints that I would normally be able to access on a website in the browser.
The problem is that the login endpoint requires a token, which I'm assuming is a JWT, when inspecting the network while logging in.
/login payload:
{
    "email": "*@*.com",
    "password": "********",
    "token": "03AFcWeA7lNwKR5KfUA7CsHb-LPduxc_R5ondn4RmMHgmmNagBeoVxo5U2ILNB5fRrNIsAPcuRVj1Dk76ZDjg9YTmxHqrvsY5uDO7KxwENwJEJvwur2ciHo_-AAxoqvz2D52sm8vDgza3sN2myzUjP4xjRQVsRJ7Nx3IRx4v5p1PcDJNsxoGhZOiEU1Wg1kHO0uhth48zd7Y7z8xZtgIgHpb9JkE2BPbXx06D8FA4BYjhujehEsnx2okF9RamM7NBlewGNinJ2EiGZh7mMk3e4uiFJ3hao_fuj0ekrHs4h1UGiAk02UbxJqLnPEqpOUiIjzfgAbM4Mvw_IPympEQCqihFPH4w_F8Aln-tHkVxS5wHWYBfxgGC4k-bXI2geSOKclYOhEnk_El_1AKROgefTBoOnQrVLKgPCRsKs6E25Izc01Y_8EAgbb6RR40woBkZDwfdliRTY0hnY8DfCsrZDT8JX6HOA4e8Dm3ArITuiSlZb_q6Y_JfMTS8Hf5awXTk8MghoISNX1oXSwuGgkLnU92-23fRXrrG74yhPTtgrylRnRTIv8eJ2BhcmNYMHVP9Q4GW77Rj8kdD6BWxlB_JetOLsGGsDeawUdwzhTwVOSwWLCzcZzyPf6BfVrcEaXUqPH83rrQ4XaGLkOIEeyMvIj4G7oKvxEv7bU8Ad7FGuGv3hizYH1Naeqg_hF7YOVitWSbJ1CDdQToxjA4i9zq1VQXwE0Bcv0Lk8wLXIz5TR6cmgh0BpIpRltDBrTerA0T9axvyJNnPMWlsHE2a-SgGnIeotAb0-qp8vN6utBu-1aH-7s5shpxP8mDgMQihHVyn1Aapb3uRURem9y9RHUPHw32RzjKR_DGaLg1oz2ApFiwBWRCu0AL-iNOErQPIUsOfKhBH57m-LLv-8D4KbeUzhVgdZE3mfL_YX6Ad1oWkHCkvRknTwpzTJNrPF_Na7yh2wFjcqVS_bS3hVTl2D9T9MLj6WO3ZN6XmV5g1t8ocW3wyQTxUdUDvqgH7K19TRH7ZsMIxsgl-PRC4NKs1a3fXyAKvMdssjBV30-LIQ2dWhl9ZNMChD5Np6uWsNmw-tAZPdJhfbGUUEfszR8lgvKxCA-DcXTJKL1AUoBpMriM3kdVUann9UaVLZtGJiGukajKqpnUHTENI9ZOwf0fmyuEtXXElZyLRoMOiz7BkQDzDNWpHpSmn0wGEqEc888uFo2IO1_hK-1RdghGNUhKVOjGqAv5O4QHbOrdYAqRVHqgMvWiQV9U62og2GxXgay5w-ZX4ldLeshqo-g3HD0IDXfjLaEPhFh1uEyOpDsgC2oRdpF_b4rr4ECz7poqxh8VZTw97RyeJPwizEa50VZVNKpUBuOl-IgpnFPCVmUZYGpsh8zJsTrL2KQYS6KFPMA930g0OaDmWnVT0J035p8Y6S86s16HT2Sp0vwrFzq5LRGje0I6_9QJ_Wz131PWEIptoi-xf6VJVEmyxkTu9JUA04CHyjKL4e84RLiEBFH15QJDcHupREYZMsbJhQByrtCh7yHhAzKW2szx2ICpNAy5O38z--TQ4pYiMWhxs9XP9YIVA2IzHUhpWkCymF1JrYn4VGHqrbqltQZOFJsiphB_G0i3BDh9eicw0UHSxqGVRIze1C-u-FnSlTzdH9h2qZrWuDXsaZN9F80FA_yobH46DOfQvJ5ELpeGiUu2Lm1KxEI5_KlxgVYlxm73o9kJMM3SL57CUHvxsKYy1x5E73QJT9DcHfa_hXZ6OO2FjvVJVqcyQi3_OyFVcp2jBA05_lbv1anxnskhDfa-mUlUkCrxBL6hMjKKUQLe_B73p3jXXxqV8nkvarHuDmuHPvSs4iDnnabtIOcqfKCelE19eE_SBea-Ra8csWebqcR7O8COIWxh4QcFOskDlU9r5hhL3bDyVrPCP4HbseWTevqUfhe-1s5btjHCPocSakrnCNbj1gPtyiPbnuvrlYKBG6Z6n625GBQLlyoQDdHPZVYa9mNfR7dH3mILYREGboqbQFOFLc2sfdZ3PwCduAruU0AVk"
}

Paying attention to the network inspector further, I see a REST request done every 30 seconds to the endpoint /validate.
/validate response (the response immediately preceding logging in):
{
    "h": "b6c7119b7e59224b",
    "m": 10,
    "n": 4000,
    "validation_id": "1d9797c2-4c7d-436f-9d75-407c570257f7"
}

Observations of /validate/:
"h" and '"validation_id"` are different in every response.
"m": 10 is always the same before and after login.
"n": 4000 is consistently the same before login.
"n": 500 is consistently the same after login.
I suspect the above is used to create the JWT, but I have no idea how to do it or how to find what method of encoding to use.
I'm using node.js request to do the request, but again I don't have the token generated.
var request = require('request');
var clientServerOptions = {
    url: 'https://*.com/login',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: '*@*.com',
        password: '********',
        token: '????????'
    }),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

